# how to run a Asp.Net website on windows 7 as server in a local network?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, iis

I was asked to run a website which was made by Asp.Net and Sql server 2008 for a local network. I have never done to do that before and I don't have a clue what to do, could you suggest me tutorial to help me to do so? I need to know how to run it there and how to config  for other computers to use it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this...

**You must have a web server** (Windows comes with one called IIS, but it may not be installed)

1. Make sure you actually have IIS
   installed! Try typing `http://localhost/` in your browser and see what happens. If nothing happens it means that you **may** not have IIS installed. See [Installing IIS (IIS
   6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/750d3137-462c-491d-b6c7-5f370d7f26cd.mspx?mfr=true)
2. Set up IIS [How to set up your first IIS Web site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972)
3. You may even need to [Install the .NET Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en) (or your server will only serve static html pages, and not asp.net pages)

**Installing your application**

Once you have done that, you can more or less just copy your application to `c:\wwwroot\inetpub\`.  Read [Installing ASP.NET Applications (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/fd7236aa-f429-4139-adc2-6834595d051f.mspx?mfr=true) for more information

**Accessing the web site from another machine**

In theory, once you have a web server running, and the application installed, you only need the `IP address` of your web server to access the application.

To find your IP address try:
`Start` -> `Run` -> type `cmd` (hit `ENTER`) -> type `ipconfig` (hit `ENTER`)

Once you have the IP address AND IIS running AND the application installed you can access you website from another machine in your LAN by just typing in the IP Address of you web server and the correct path to your application. If you put your application in a directory called `NewApp`, you will need to type something like `http://your_ip_address/NewApp/default.aspx`

**Turn off your firewall**

If you do have a firewall turn it off while you try connecting for the first time, you can sort that out later.

Comment: thanks, how about the Sql server?

Comment: @ePezhman you can add your database also look at this link for more info  ..http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1247-how-to-host-aspnet-application-on-the-web-server-iis-.aspx